# sh + how to use array in sh in order to print all values in array

Tags: arrays, linux, shell, sh

I want to use arrays in my sh script

my target is to create array for following values - a b c
and print all values by the array

I successes to print each array , but I failed to print all values in the array

Please look on the following example

**set each value in arr**

```
n=1
eval arr$n=a
n=2
eval arr$n=b
n=3
eval arr$n=c
```

**print each value from arr**

```
n=1
eval echo \$arr$n
a
n=2
eval echo \$arr$n
b
n=3
eval echo \$arr$n
 c
```

now I want to print all values with the $arr

and I get the following instead to get "a b c"

```
n="*"

eval echo \$arr$n

{*}*
```

the values should be:

```
a b c
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are creating is not an array at all. It's just 3 independent variables called `arr1`, `arr2` and `arr3`. You're probably working in an empty directory, so when you say

```
eval echo \$arr$n
```

`$arr` is expanded to nothing, as it does not exist, and `$n` is expanded to `*` as there are no files in the directory. Should there be, `$n`, containing `*`, would be expanded to the list of files in the directory.

Welcome to shell programming. :-)